# Does it make sense to do the power analysis if one of the sample proportions is 0%?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, statistical-power, sample, ab-test

Can we have any sample size if one of the sample proportions is 0. I mean even the slightest difference detected between the two groups would be because of the treatment in this case, and hence I do not see any reason why the power analysis should be done.

For example, in the calculator [here](https://select-statistics.co.uk/calculators/sample-size-calculator-two-proportions/), if I enter group1 sample proportion as 0 and group2 sample proportion as 1, I get some sample size. My question is why should there be some specific sample size? Why isn't it the case that any sample size should suffice since we expect a 0 event rate in group 1? This means whatever we get in group 2 with the samples is because of the treatment? Isn't that the case?

Comment: You provided no background information.  And power/sample size estimation does not use any observed proportions.

Comment: It is usually more meaningful to conduct power analysis before you see the sample

Comment: Added some more context with the edit

Comment: This is still lacking context and you give no explanation of why your question title talks about "sample proportions" in the context of a power analysis. You do mention that you entered sample proportions into an online calculator - but if you read the instructions for the calculator, it tells you *not* to enter the observed sample proportions, but rather the *expected* proportions. On its own, the phrase "sample proportion" refers to the former, not the latter. Until you clarify what you are really asking, I think the answers you get may not deal with your underlying question

Comment: If you clarified the context, it might at least be clearer whether your underlying issue is something to do with wanting to perform a power analysis retrospectively (which as @Henry says is generally not advised, and is not what the online calculator you linked to is recommending you to do), is really concerned with a (hypothesised) population proportion being zero rather than a sample proportion, or something else altogether

Comment: @Silverfish For my part, I interpreted the question as "Why would anyone bother with a priori sample size calculations if they think that '0%' is a plausible scenario for one of the groups?", and I answered to that. But I agree that some clarification  would be welcome, in particular if this is not a theoretical question, but a question about an actual study the original poster is conducting or plan to conduct. I also realize that OP might be misinterpreting what power analysis is about, so I agree entirely - additional information would be helpful to give an appropriate answer.

Comment: @J-J-J Yes I found your interpretation quite plausible. There's definitely an interesting question in here that would be relevant to people beyond the original poster. I'm hoping the OP can make the edits to really bring this out - hopefully any points raised by me or other commenters above are seen as helpful and constructive. The point of closing the question is really just so the OP gets a chance to finesse the question before reopening it, because questions still open to answers while undergoing editing tend to get "messy", with different people answering different versions of the question

Answer (score 4):

Consider the table below. It's a sample *maybe* drawn from a population where group A has 1% chance of having a given event, while group B has 0% chance. Or maybe this is a sample from a population where the percentages of group A and group B are equal (1%), you don't know - if you knew, why would you bother with sampling in the first place?

|  | Event | No event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Group A | 1 | 109 |
| Group B | 0 | 110 |

Given the table above, how confident are you that there's a real difference between group A and group B? Not very confident, probably. A statistical test wouldn't even be necessary to tell that this sample is unreliable to judge the difference between A and B. So any sample size won't suffice, and you just need to collect more observations.

---

As a side note, to determine sample size, you should think about a range of plausible effect sizes of interest, find the one requiring the largest sample size, and retain this sample size to conduct your study.

For example, you mention a plausible scenario where there's 0% chance of event in group 1, and 1% chance of event in group 2. But if you think that it's also plausible to have 1% chance in group 1 and 2% in group 2, and you don't want to miss that, you should conduct sample size calculations for this plausible scenario too -in particular when it will certainly require a larger sample size than the 0%/1% scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of power analysis is to understand the level of accuracy of a hypothesis test in cases where the alternative hypothesis is true, which then tells you about the risk of making a Type II error in the test.  This is useful information about the test irrespective of the actual result that occurs when you run the test on your data.  However, it is particularly useful in the case where you accept the null hypothesis, because it is precisely in this case that you may have made a Type II error.

It is not clear from your question what you are testing or which particular hypothesis test you are using for this purpose.  Nevertheless, generally speaking, knowing a sample proportion does not tell you the sample size, nor does a sample proportion of zero imply any particular outcome for the test, or preclude the usefulness of power analysis for the test.